# Помогите с модулем pyttsx3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyttsx3

Вроде бы я всё правильно скачал, но при написании кода мне выдаёт ошибку.

```
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.say("I will speak this text")
engine.runAndWait()
```

И выдаёт такую ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Comp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 20, in init
    eng = _activeEngines[driverName]
  File "C:\Users\Comp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\weakref.py", line 131, in __getitem__
    o = self.data[key]()
KeyError: None

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Comp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\drivers\sapi5.py", line 3, in <module>
    from comtypes.gen import SpeechLib  # comtypes
ImportError: cannot import name 'SpeechLib' from 'comtypes.gen' (C:\Users\Comp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\comtypes\gen\__init__.py)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Comp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 123, in WINFUNCTYPE
    return _win_functype_cache[(restype, argtypes, flags)]
KeyError: (<class 'ctypes.HRESULT'>, (<class 'comtypes.automation.tagVARIANT'>, <class 'ctypes.wintypes.LP_c_long'>), 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jarvis.py", line 4, in <module>
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
  File "C:\Users\Comp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 22, in init
    eng = Engine(driverName, debug)
  File "C:\Users\Comp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\engine.py", line 30, in __init__
    self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)
  File "C:\Users\Comp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\driver.py", line 50, in __init__
    self._module = importlib.import_module(name)
  File "C:\Users\Comp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Comp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\drivers\sapi5.py", line 6, in <module>
    engine = comtypes.client.CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice")
  File "C:\Users\Comp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\__init__.py", line 250, in CreateObject
    return _manage(obj, clsid, interface=interface)
  File "C:\Users\Comp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\__init__.py", line 188, in _manage
    obj = GetBestInterface(obj)
  File "C:\Users\Comp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\__init__.py", line 110, in GetBestInterface
    mod = GetModule(tlib)
  File "C:\Users\Comp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\_generate.py", line 110, in GetModule
    mod = _CreateWrapper(tlib, pathname)
  File "C:\Users\Comp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\_generate.py", line 184, in _CreateWrapper
    mod = _my_import(fullname)
  File "C:\Users\Comp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\_generate.py", line 24, in _my_import
    return __import__(fullname, globals(), locals(), ['DUMMY'])
  File "C:\Users\Comp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\comtypes\gen\_C866CA3A_32F7_11D2_9602_00C04F8EE628_0_5_4.py", line 2821, in <module>
    ISpeechBaseStream._methods_ = [
  File "C:\Users\Comp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\comtypes\__init__.py", line 329, in __setattr__
    self._make_methods(value)
  File "C:\Users\Comp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\comtypes\__init__.py", line 698, in _make_methods
    prototype = WINFUNCTYPE(restype, *argtypes)
  File "C:\Users\Comp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 125, in WINFUNCTYPE
    class WinFunctionType(_CFuncPtr):
TypeError: item 1 in _argtypes_ passes a union by value, which is unsupported.
```

Comment: Возможно, питон 3.8 не поддерживается. Я тестировал на 3.7 и проблем не было, попробуйте на 3.7 проверить

Comment: @gil9red, Python 3.8.0 и 3.8.1 поддерживаются нормально, работаю только на этих версиях и всё выводит

Comment: Вот у меня точно такая же ошибка. Винда 7
Заметил что проблема начинается со строчки init()

Comment: Как вариант, для решения этой проблемы можно попробовать обновить библиотеку. Возможно, ваша версия `pyttsx3` не поддерживается на вашей версии `python`

Answer (score 2):

Не понимаю в чём у вас ошибка, но я написал этот код и он прекрасно работает:

```
import pyttsx3

tts = pyttsx3.init()

tts.say('Добрый вечер всем ! Вы изучаете питон!')

tts.runAndWait()
```

Всё тоже самое, что и у вас. Отпишитесь в комментах работает у вас или нет.

Comment: Не помогло, всё та же ошибка

Answer (score 2):

Данная проблема решается через костыль(я нашел только такое решение). Через дополнительный модуль записываешь ответ системы(голосового помощника) в аудиофайл и через код его запускаешь.

```
import os
from gtts import gTTS

def talk(what):
    tts = gTTS(what, lang = 'ru')  #определяем что говорим и на каком языке
    tts.save('hello.mp3')  #создаем аудиофайл
    os.system('hello.mp3')  #проигрываем созданный аудиофайл
```

При запуске программы будет открываться аудиофайл и проигрываться.