# Не работает pyttsx3

Tags: python, pyttsx3

Программа запускается без ошибок, но ничего не произносит, а так не должно быть, что делать?

```
import pyttsx3

engine = pyttsx3.init('dummy')
engine.say("Hello")
engine.runAndWait()
```

Если что, у меня `Windows 10`, `python3.8`, `pywin32` и `pipywin32` установлены.

Comment: Драйвер dummy создан именно для того, чтобы ничего не произносить. Поэтому так **должно** быть и программа ведёт себя абсолютно правильно.

Comment: А если убираю dummy, то программа выдает ошибку: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mikhail\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 20, in init
    eng = _activeEngines[driverName]
  File "C:\Users\Mikhail\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\weakref.py", line 131, in __getitem__
    o = self.data[key]()  и т.д.

Comment: Такая же ошибка, как здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1082242/Помогите-с-модулем-pyttsx3